# Add new cell with expanded UITablviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, expand

In my application, I have done Expanded table view cell inside that again I need to expand the cell.I Am facing the problem with again inserting expanded cell.Is it possible to do?

```
//cellForRowAtIndexPath:

 [cell.expandButton addTarget:self action:@selector(expandAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 if (indexPath.item < [array count] + 1) {
        NSLog(@"Show one cell”);

 }else{

        NSLog(@"Show another cell")

 }

//Button action
-(void) expandAction:(UIButton*)sender{
    if (indexPath.item < [array count] + 1) {
        NSLog(@"Show one cell”);
    }else{

        NSLog(@"Show another cell")

    }

}
```

Comment: with out code how can help

Comment: else try with RATreeview

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i need to implement without any libraries.

Answer (score 0):

How do you generate your tableView data? If you use array of objects, then you could make it kind of like that:

CellItem class saves cell state

```
@interface CellItem : NSObject
@property BOOL isExpanded;
@end
```

Your custom cell class. Setup method customize your cell depending on CellItem object state

```
@interface ExpandableCell : UITableViewCell
- (void)setupWith:(CellItem *)cellItem;
@end

@implementation ExpandableCell
- (void)setupWith:(CellItem *)cellItem {

    if(cellItem.isExpanded) {
        //Expand your cell
    } else {
        //Don't exp and
    }
}
@end
```

Array of objects where you get data for your tableView

```
@property NSArray<CellItem *> *items;
```

Protocol, which defines methods for cell state delegate. Implement this methods in class, which is also delegate of yourtableView. Call this method from cell everytime user expand / close it. In implementation save cellItem in items arrays.

```
@protocol ExpandableCellDelegate
- (void)cellDidChangeStateWithCellItem: (CellItem *)cellItem;
@end
```

UITableView cells are reusable, so everytime cell appears on a screen you should customize it again.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CellItem *cellItem = self.items[indexPath.row];
    ExpandableCell *cell = (ExpandableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"InsertYourCEllID"];
    [cell setupWith:cellItem];
    return cell;
}
```